# PHP access to custom Apache API

Tags: php, apache

I have a collection I want exposed to php.
I don't want it to ever leave memory, so I don't think I can use a php extension.
I don't want to access it via IPC, so I don't want the memcache stuff.

I am willing to modify / rebuild apache and php to accomplish this.

Perhaps:
call into apache like:

```
void* GetMyThing(void*ptr)
```

and

```
SetMyThing(void*ptr)
```

These two new functions would be available like any other normal php function.

Has something like this been done before?  Any pointers?
Any known existing php functions that do this that I could mimic?

Maybe requests for this data can be redirected to a fastcgi instance that never leaves memory?

Not sure what the best approach is.

Thanks